# Matlab Java builder?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I am trying to convert Matlab code to something that I can put as a server application, Java if possible. I have Matlab 2008a installed, AND matlab compiler runtime (or so at least I think - the directory is there). Running deploytool from the matlab command line works, but when I try to start a new project there's nothing there about Java.

The result of getenv JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16". I have set this variable myself, AFTER installing matlab (not sure if it's connected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Matlab Java Builder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) is a separate product from the Matlab Compiler. Have you purchased a license for it?

Comment: I am not sure, since it was installed in my work's computer not by me, but I guess this is the problem...